# Updating a column in mysql by added to the middle of the string?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I currently have a column (control_reference) setup as a `varchar(120)` with the data that looks something like this `15591_8571`. The data in this column changes the first number but the second number is always the same.  I would like to add something to the middle of this so the `varchar` would look something like this in the end. Remember I have hundreds of these so I wanted to find a way to change them all.

Current values in control_reference

- 15591_8571
- 16772_8571
- 20541_8571

New values in control_reference

- 15591_I18n_8571
- 16772_I18n_8571
- 20541_I18n_8571

I know I can use a simple `UPDATE 'database.table' SET 'control_reference'='15591_I18n_8571' WHERE'id'='some_number';` but I have a lot of them to do.

Answer (score 1):

If all rows in the table need to be updated, try:

```
UPDATE database.table SET control_reference=REPLACE(control_reference, '_', '_I18n_')
```

To limit the update to rows that match that pattern, add something like:

```
WHERE control_reference REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function or stored procedure with `REPLACE` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and use it.

Simple Usage of REPLACE sysntax

```
SELECT REPLACE('15591_8571', '_', '_I18n_') AS NewValue;
```

Result :

```
15591_I18n_8571
```